# Vertical text aligning in custom checkbox implementation

Tags: css, checkbox, custom-controls, vertical-alignment

While implementing custom checkbox I came across the problem of **vertical aligning one-line and two-lines text** next to the image which imitates checkbox with one css style.

See the described situation in this [image](http://prntscr.com/3b58gg).

I have played a lot with `vertical-aling`, `display: inline-block` and `line-height`, the solutions occured to work separetely **only** for one-line text or **only** for two and more lines text. In the end I figured out that the behavior can be reached by `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. But I'the sample onnot happy with this solution.

Is there any other way to reach the same behavior?

Here is the sample html to play with:

```html
<div class="block">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="input" type="checkbox">
        <span class="image"></span>
        <span class="text">Some text</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="input" type="checkbox">
        <span class="image"></span>
        <span class="text">Some very very very <br> very very very long text</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And here is the `display: table-cell` style solution:

```css
.block {
    margin-top: 10px
}
.checkbox {
    display: table;
}
.checkbox .input {
    display: none;
}
.image {
    background: red;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

See the same on [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/79T6d/1/).

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/79T6d/3/ (which uses `display:inline-block` instead of `table-cell`)

Comment: This was my first solution, but it goes wrong when the line it too long for one line and is **not** broken with `<br>` elements, the line in this case flows below the image. The way to solve **this** problem is to set some width value, which is not good if you want to have fixed width image and flow-width text. Maybe you know some other way to forbid line to go below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/79T6d/2/

```
SEE ON JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/79T6d/2/
```

Comment: That's a good solution, thank you. But I think you mean your solution does not need `display: table-cell`, so I replaced it with `display: inline-block`. And in case to support `.checkbox` block height (otherwise absolute positioned blocks easily overflow each other) I set `.checkbox { line-height: 35px; display: inline-block; }` and dropped the line-height in `.text` element. See [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/79T6d/4/).